# How to delete some extra whitespace created with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was doing a simple navigation bar for a React website using React router.
Everything works except for some extra whitespace created on the left side of my 'Home' Route (see the code below).

After some investigation, it seems that the 'exact' keyword in the main route is creating this extra whitespace. On developer tools, I can see that an extra text node with "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" was created in that point.
I deleted the index.scss file and did my reset on the app.scss.

Does anybody know how to fix it?
Thanks!

[image]

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import Home from './pages/Home'
import About from './pages/About'

import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return (
        <HashRouter>
            <nav>
                <ul className="header">
                    <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <main id="yellow-section">
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            </main>
        </HashRouter>
        )
    }

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => {
    return(
        <p>This is my HOME</p>  
        )
    }

export default Home
```

**About.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const About = () => {
    return(
        <p>This is my ABOUT</p>
        )
    }

export default About
```

**App.scss**

```
/* VARIABLES */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*** NAVIGATION ***/
nav {
  background-color: blue;
}

/*** MAIN ***/
main {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  }
```

Comment: Don't see any extra spaces https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-grass-rycp6

Comment: I uploaded the post. This behavior happens in chrome and firefox as well.

Comment: Try wrapping backticks around `\`<p>This is my HOME</p>\``, does that help?

Comment: no, it doesn't work.

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally, and have multiple apps w/ React Router that don't do this--I suspect something else is at play.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I solved it by css. This way the *&nbsp;* elements remain in the code, however, they are not visible.

```
#yellow-section {
  margin-top: -1rem; /*the font size*/
}
```

Anybody has a better idea to completely remove the *&nbsp;* elements?